# Global static inline variable with potential class redefinition across translation units - Is this particular case undefined behavior in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, inline, undefined-behavior

First of all: I want to state, that I (suppose to) understand in general the C++17 changes for inline variables and how they work.

For my concrete totally simplified use case, I have some kind of a definitions .inl file, that looks like this:

```
MY_STRUCT_BEGIN(PotentiallyUB)
MY_STRUCT_END(PotentiallyUB)
```

And the according macros are defined here inside a header:

```
#define MY_STRUCT_BEGIN(myStructName) \
static inline constexpr struct myStructName##Type\
{ \
  static inline constexpr unsigned long MyValue1 = __COUNTER__ + 1; \
  static inline constexpr unsigned long MyValue2 = __COUNTER__ + 1; \
  static inline constexpr unsigned long MyTranslationUnitIndependentDiff = MyValue2 - MyValue1;

#define MY_STRUCT_END(myStructName) \
} myStructName {};
```

I'm totally aware of the fact, that the usage of the built-in COUNTER might be questioned here in general, that's another possible issue I do not want to address here. Here it is required to emphasize my concerns. I also know, that static constexpr variables are implicitly inlined since C++17, just added it to make things clear on first sight.

Now my question: Is this potentially undefined behavior as soon as the .inl file gets (accidentally or desired) processed across multiple translation units? In terms of undefined behavior here, I meant the invariant usage of the difference of MyValue2 - MyValue1 in the definition of MyTranslationUnitIndependentDiff especially.

The standard states

> There may be more than one definition of an inline function or variable (since C++17) in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit and (for non-static inline functions and variables (since C++17)) all definitions are identical. For example, an inline function or an inline variable (since C++17) may be defined in a header file that is #include'd in multiple source files.

And

> If an inline function or variable (since C++17) with external linkage is defined differently in different translation units, the behavior is undefined.

Especially with focus on the last phrase, I'd currently say, the code shouldn't lead to potential undefined behavior. But I feel like I might have missed something here.

**Appendix: What I want to achieve**

I actually want instances of these Macro defined structs as constexpr objects available across all translation units, if possible via external linkage. I doubt that the external linkage is really possible in the way the declaration of these objects could be handled in a constexpr context project-wide. If it would be possible, the question about UB should actually not differ since the macro solely affects value initialization and not the definition.

Comment: If you want to avoid UB, you probably need to ensure that `__COUNTER__` is the same when instantiating `PotentiallyUB` across all translation units, which is not hard to control.

Comment: Thanks. I added details to my concerns about the UB. Premise: I'm not able to control the (reset-) behavior of the COUNTER.

Comment: PS: To make things clearer here: I want to understand the potential UB here in general, so __COUNTER__ could be replaced with something translation unit depending I have no explicit control of.

Comment: @Holt PS: See my updated information. Effectively, I'm already doing what you suggested. But my actual question is about the UB potential here with focus on these static members and the global constexpr instances of my structs since the initial COUNTER value must be stored somewhere in a similar way since I want to ensure constexpr-usage, so it's solely a shift of the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the code in an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace
{
    ...
}
```

Then each translation unit will have its own separate namespace which are guaranteed not to collide.

Comment: Hm, I see no effective difference to the approach within the global namespace since the linkage should already be internal!? But the longer I think about the issue here, the longer I think my actual intention might be not that clear as I thought it would be. Internal linkage here might not be desired in doubt.

Comment: @Secundi • An anonymous namespace in a header file would be my last choice, in order to avoid ODR.  Otherwise, [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) is [IFNDR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ndr) and [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), which is worth avoiding.

Comment: @Eljay Yes I'd really like to avoid that. For this particular case, it should be ok since I'm only interested in relative values between translation unit local absolute ones. But that smells anyways a bit...